# How do you share variable values across multiple blocks within an email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, variable

I have a `@variable1` defined in an email HTML content block that is defined.  When the email iterator starts, I would like to use the value of `@variable1` in a second HTML content block.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ampscript process from the [top down](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/orderOfOperations.htm) so as long as the variable is defined in a content block above where you are referencing it, it will work.